# advancejava, TOMCAT server,html,css

Tags: html

working on advancejava.i had designed a page in html and included a background image in it.now the problem is when i m opening the html file directly, the background image is visible but when starting tomcat and writing a correct url in chrome the background image is not visible all other elements(like links) are working properly.HELP!!!!!
the html code for the same is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">


            body {background-repeat:no-repeat;
                 background-size:100% 100%;}



            ul {list-style-type:none;
                margin: 30px auto;
                text-align: center
                }
        .myButton1 {
                    <!--background-color:#44c767;-->
                    -moz-border-radius:28px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
                    border-radius:28px;
                    border:1px solid #18ab29;
                    display:inline-block;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    color:#ffffff;
                    margin-bottom:0px;
                    margin-top:525px;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    font-size:17px;
                    padding:16px 31px;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
                  }
        .myButton1:hover {
                    background-color:#5cbf2a;
                    }
        .myButton1:active {
                    position:relative;
                    top:1px;
                    }
        .myButton2 {
                    <!--background-color:#44c767;-->
                    -moz-border-radius:28px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
                    border-radius:28px;
                    border:1px solid #18ab29;
                    display:inline-block;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    color:#ffffff;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    font-size:17px;
                    padding:16px 31px;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
                  }
        .myButton2:hover {
                    background-color:#5cbf2a;
                    }
        .myButton2:active {
                    position:relative;
                    top:1px;
                    }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body  background="images\welcome.png">

        <ul >
            <li><a href="about.html" class="mybutton1" title="take a tour..!!">It's my first time here</a></li>
            <li><a href="register" class="mybutton2" title="i have been here before..!!">I know the drill </a></li>

        </ul> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @chris85 sorry! my bad..!!

Answer (score 0):

in image url instead of using extension png use jpg and make sure that the image in pc is saved with jpg,jpeg format.